# Can you join two tables using a template that has columns as a list of column names from respective tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to use the template table that has 2 columns to create a desired Result table using:

- The first column: a list of all the column names in **Table A**.
- The Second Column : a list of all column names in **Table B**.

From the table below I want to use the column names from TableA and Table B and compare the values joining them on their ID.

**Template Table**

| TableA | TableB |
| --- | --- |
| Id | Id |
| Fruits1 | Fruits2 |
| Vegetables1 | Vegetables2 |

**Table A**

| Id | Fruits1 | Vegetables1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Carrot |
| 2 | Banana | Pumpkin |

**Table B**

| Id | Fruits2 | Vegetable2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Carrot |
| 2 | Banana | Onion |

**Desired Result**

| ID | Fruits1 | Fruits2 | Comparison1 | **Vegetable1** | **Vegetable2** | Comparison2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple | Apple | True | Carrot | Carrot | True |
| 2 | Banana | Banana | True | Pumpkin | Onion | False |

How can I use the Template table to join Table A and Table B using the ID to produce the above table?

I tried Unpivoting the mapping table but I could not find a way.

Comment: You are looking for *dynamic SQL*, ie generate a query programmatically, then execute it. More than often, that’s a flag that indicates a bad design. Maybe `TableA` and `TableB` should be just a single table to start with.

Comment: Table A and B are just being compaired

Answer (score 0):

It seems the best way to do this would be dynamic SQL.

You need to build up a list of columns

```sql
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

SELECT @sql =
  STRING_AGG(
    CONCAT(
      '
  a.',
      QUOTENAME(t.TableA),
      '1,
  b.',
      QUOTENAME(t.TableB),
      '2,
  Comparison',
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
      ' = CASE WHEN b.',
      QUOTENAME(t.TableA),
      ' = a.',
      QUOTENAME(t.TableB),
      ' THEN CAST(1 AS bit) ELSE CAST(0 AS bit) END'
    ),
    ',
')
FROM Template t
WHERE t.TableA <> 'ID';

SET @sql = '
SELECT
  a.ID,
' + @sql + '
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON b.ID = a.ID;
`;

PRINT @sql;   -- your friend

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```